# VS2008 MFC projects behave differently

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mfc, projects-and-solutions

In VS 2008, I have two MFC based managed C++ projects A and B.

For project A project->properties->common properties, Framework and references-> Add new reference causes a panel to appear with following four tabs: 
.Net , COM, Projects , Browse , recent

For project B project->properties->common properties, Framework and references-> Add new reference causes a panel to appear with following only one tab: 
Projects

Which attributes of the two projects might be different ( and hence causing the above difference)?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that Project has some .cpp files that was compiled with /clr option. 
Again i repeat, some .cpp files ( not entire project ) was compiled with "Common Language Runtime Support (/clr) " . You can see this option when the .cpp file is selected and you click on project->Properties. 
Selecting thsi option for ( even ) a single file in Project B solved the problem.